# Thunderbird Lightning not able to show shared google calendars?

Tags: thunderbird, google-calendar, lightning

I was wonder if someone could help me out, I've set up Google calendars so that i can access another persons calendar and it sync's to my android phone beautifully, i can see both my events and the other persons, even separates them into different colors.

So anyhow - now i go back to my mozilla thunderbird and it only ever downloads MY calendar and not the other persons? is this a limitation of the lightning plugin? does anyone know?

Ta.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the other Google calendars separatly to Lighning. There is a url every calendar has (go to your calendar settings). Maybe the calendar is not public, then you have to authenticate with your eg. google account.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can add more than one calendar to Thunderbird/Lightning, all that will happen is that you will see the calendars displayed.  To allow authentication of the different calendars, use the format https://user:pass@servername/bla/bla/calendar in the URL that you add when you create the calendar.  This gives each calendar a unique "domain" in the eyes of TB/Lightning, to allow authentication to happen again for each new calendar.

There doesn't seem to be a way to see the free/busy status of the calendar owner though, which is quite shocking imho.  What's the point of a calendar when you cannot share it / use what others have shared with you?

The big downside to doing it this way is that you need each user's logon credentials, making this only feasible in a small trusted environment, not anywhere else.

Comment: To whoever downvoted my answer: Why??  Have you actually tested this?  I have spent a great deal of time on this on over time and the description I've given is pretty accurate.  So if you disagree, please comment here or provide your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following the [instructions on the google website](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37648?hl=en#zippy=%2Csync-your-google-calendar-view-edit%2Cget-your-calendar-view-only) you can find the "Secret address in iCal format" (Refer to the section on "Get your calendar (view only)"). For me the URL was actually labelled "Public address in iCal format", probably that's how it's called in cases where you only have read access to a calendar.

Once you have this URL, you can add it to Thunderbird:

- In Thunderbird, go to File -> New -> Calendar
- Choose "On the network"
- Leave the username empty. As a location, enter the URL you found in the previous step. Tick the box "This location doesn't require credentials".
- Hit "Find calendars" and you should be able to see the correct calendar (for me it was named with a default name "basic", but it had the correct information)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your quick response. **I apologize for being guilty** of not chasing through all the possible options in Thunderbird.I had done some investigation by questioning on the thunderbird site but couldn't nail down a solution through them. I went back to basics and tried almost everything on the toolbar and finally found the answer in VIEW. Pretty darn obvious but I had missed it. Thanks again .... this can be closed now

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).